# Dynamic SPARQL query to get data between classes represented as Venn diagrams

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am building a semantics application where i have list of all Classes and Sub classes available in my RDF repository. Then the user drags the classes or subclasses on to a drawing area to form a venn diagram. Suppose i have two classes, Class A and Class B, the user drags them and i need to fire a SPARQL query to get if these two classes have any relationship, if so i need to fetch the data that is common between these two classes.Suppose the user adds another class, say Class C, then i need to fetch realtionship and the data that exists between these classes.

I need SPARQL queries for the following:
             1. SPARQL query to check if relationship exists between the classes, A,B and C. The relationship i mean here is , Is there any common data that exists between these three classes, if not which classes have relationship.
             2. SPARQL query to get the common data between these classes, example, AnB or BnC or AnBnC or AU(BnC)(as in Venn diagram terms)

Please help me in this regard as i am new to SPARQL queries.

Comment: It is easier to respond to concrete questions - a complete, minimal example including valid sample data, what you have tried, what happens and what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "relation". I guess by AnB you mean "number of instances of A and B" etc. You can get the counts as follows:

- AnB: `select (count(distinct ?x) as ?c) {?x a <A>. ?x a <B>}`
- AuB: `select (count(distinct ?x) as ?c) {{?x a <A>} union {?x a <B>}}`
- A-B: `select (count(distinct ?x) as ?c) {?x a <A> filter not exists {?x a <B>}}`